# Remove Write-Protection on Network Drive

Tags: permissions, network-drive, windows-10-desktop

I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise. I have created a folder for a task and mapped it to drive V:\, a network drive. In trying to copy a file to it, I receive the error "The disk is write-protected. Remove the write-protection or use another disk."

Question: How do I change the permissions and remove the write-protection for a NETWORK drive (not USB or local)?

Answer (score 0):

1. right click to the network drive
2. open properties
3. click on the security register
4. click on edit then you should find it